# How to resolve AWS resource ( ARN ) arn not reachable in a particular region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to embed a AWS Quiksight Dashboard in one of my application. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the AWS guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-setup.html

I have created the AWS role with the required policy, at the last step when I try t fetch the embedded dashboard URL, I get the following error. Not sure what is the issue.

The function I call is

```
    response1 = client.get_dashboard_embed_url(
        AwsAccountId="999999999999",
        DashboardId='29dfd0b7-844e-4867-9a3c-77acdd647d1d',
        IdentityType='IAM',
        SessionLifetimeInMinutes=120,
        UserArn=arn
    )
```

Value 'arn:aws:iam::9999999999999:role/EmbeddQuickSight' at 'userArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-1' )

Comment: What region is your client configured to? And in what region have you created the dashboard?

Comment: My client and the region both are created in region 'us-east-1"

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/get-dashboard-embed-url.html), `UserArn` can't be an IAM role. It needs to be one of the following:

- Active Directory (AD) users or group members
- Invited nonfederated users
- IAM users and IAM role-based sessions authenticated through Federated Single Sign-On using SAML, OpenID Connect, or IAM federation.

I could imagine that this is the underlying issue.